# Merge or replace the "singlequotes", "singlequote" and "single-quote" tags with "single-quotes"

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

There are three existing tags here that I think should be merged together into a single new one: [singlequotes](/questions/tagged/singlequotes), [singlequote](/questions/tagged/singlequote) and [single-quote](/questions/tagged/single-quote) to be replaced by [single-quotes](/questions/tagged/single-quotes). I would do this myself if I could but I am unable to create new tags and I believe the tagging system would now block the creation of such a tag as it would be classed as a duplicate.

Comment: FYI, you're right, [tag:single-quotes] can't be created since it conflicts with both [tag:singlequotes] and [tag:single-quote].

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary. **Better solution:** Get rid of these tags. They are useless and the majority of cases were actually referring to either [escaping](/questions/tagged/escaping) or [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax). There were only a few that didn't refer to either, mostly questions like "how do I remove single quotes?" which is a complete meta-use of the tag.

All of these tags have been removed from the questions, except for one which was migrated and cannot be edited by us mortals.

Comment: I can't decided whether I agree with you or not, but either way, this is a different answer to that of [my other similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125666/merge-or-replace-the-doublequotes-tag-with-the-more-sensible-double-quotes) which relates to the tag [tag:double-quotes] which has now been marked as [tag:status-completed]!

Comment: @ninesided: I would say that the [double-quotes] tag is also a meta tag, which would follow this same pattern I just outlined. The problem is most people don't care to actually go through these tags and retag them appropriately, so they get left alone.

Comment: is there not an admin tool to rename/merge tags without having to go and edit each question? In cases like these, once the legacy tags are removed, they can't be recreated due to the new "duplicate tag" policy.

Comment: They have admin tools, but that can only change one tag to one tag. In this case, there are two separate tags to which these correlate, and also some cases where the tag just needs removed. There's no magical tool that can sort through the questions and figure out *which* tags that each question belongs.