# Quote tags cleanup

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The quote tags are:

- [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) x850
- [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) x229
  "The Common Lisp quote special operator" - most (210) questions not tagged with [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp).
  Create a [lisp-quote](/questions/tagged/lisp-quote) and synonymize [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) with [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes).
- [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes) x287
  Perhaps synonymize with [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes).
- [smart-quotes](/questions/tagged/smart-quotes) x33
  Perhaps synonymize with [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes).
- [magic-quotes](/questions/tagged/magic-quotes) x52
  [Only 2 not tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-quotes+-php) [php](/questions/tagged/php).
  Synonymize with [magic-quotes-gpc](/questions/tagged/magic-quotes-gpc)?
- [unquote](/questions/tagged/unquote) x7
  "A F# testing library" - 3 questions not tagged with F#
  Just remove the tag from those 3 or replace it with something else?

The reason I think we should synonymize [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes) and [smart-quotes](/questions/tagged/smart-quotes) is that I don't think many of those questions are actually *specific* to those type of quotes - most of those can probably be generalized to any type of quotes, or just any type of character for what it's worth. And there aren't enough cases where it is actually specific to those types of quotes to justify a tag. So, if these *will* be synonymized with [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes), we should probably do a tag cleanup of all 3 first.

Or should we just make [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes), [smart-quotes](/questions/tagged/smart-quotes), [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) and [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) burn, as was suggested for [single-quote](/questions/tagged/single-quote) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125678/206447)?

Comment: `smart-quotes` is a distinct thing that should not be merged.  `magic-quotes` and the `-gpc` one are distinct and should not be merged.  `unquote` is distinct and should not be merged.

Comment: @Charles [A moderator said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125678/206447) "They are useless and the majority of cases were actually referring to either escaping or syntax" about [tag:single-quote]. Logically the same argument is likely to apply to [tag:double-quotes] and [tag:smart-quotes]. And "is a distinct thing" probably needs a bit of elaboration. And (w.r.t. [tag:magic-quotes] and [tag:unquote]) I'm **not** saying we should merge all of them together - is that not clear from the question?

Answer (score 1):

[magic-quotes](/questions/tagged/magic-quotes) has nothing to do with the rest. This term has very special meaning and shouldn't be mixed with the other quotes.
[magic-quotes-gpc](/questions/tagged/magic-quotes-gpc) has to be synonymized with [magic-quotes](/questions/tagged/magic-quotes), as a sub-ordinate term.

As a sidenote, I don't understand the desire for such a formalization. These tags are intended to help with the search. So, there is no point in tagging magic-quotes related question with just [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) as people would look for magic quotes, not quotes.

And 100 questions are FAR EASIER to browse than 10000. So, I'd rather leave them alone.

Comment: [tag:magic-quotes] has to do with the rest in the sense that it contains the text "quotes". Note that I'm **not** suggesting it be made a synonym of [tag:quotes] in the question.

Comment: I am sorry, but you don't quite understand the meaning of the word "sense". It is not something like "appearance". There is the word "cat" contained in the "catalog". It doesn't mean they have anything in common. Magic quotes is a certain term, with particular meaning of its own and has nothing to do with other quotes. Anyone who is looking for magic quotes, is looking for magic quotes, not quotes.

Comment: Ok, the link between them may not be particularly significant. It's actually a rather different request, but at less than 100 questions, I didn't see that as warranting it's own question.

Comment: What's wrong with 100 questions? Let me remind you please that Stack Overflow is not your personal playground to practice bureaucracy. But a place where people looking for answers. And even one single question is all right, if it's on particular technology.

Comment: I suppose that's where we disagree then. In my book, a single question does *not* warrant a tag and a retag request of tags with 10000s of questions is greatly more significant than those with 100s of questions.

Comment: Well, you'd better keep your book off this site.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't understand your retagging business, may be it's all right. But if it's about erasing tags for rarely used technologies that have 5-10 questions on them, you'd better reconsider that. And remember the purpose of the site.

Comment: I'll accept having a tag for 5-10 questions, but not for a single question.

Comment: @Dukeling every being have to have a place to start from. When there was first question on handlersocket, I rather fertilized it with bounty instead of weeding it out. Now it only count for six, but it doesn't matter at all. It's great technology and it's actually a *shame* that it has so little representation on SO. And you want to make it even worse, weeding out even these weak seedlings. I still see no point in this business at all.